# How to configure more than one Symfony2 projects on the same server

Tags: php, apache, symfony

I'm working on 2 Symfony2 projects on my server, but I have an error if I execute them.
Let's call the projects A and B.

If I restart the apache2 service on my server and I enter on the web of project A, then the project B displays this error:

> FatalErrorException: Error: Class 'Ps\PdfBundle\PsPdfBundle' not found
>   in /var/www/gesalight/gesaudit2/app/AppKernel.php line 19

Otherwise if I restart again the apache2 service and I enter first on project B, then the project A displays the same error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Acme\ContacteBundle\AcmeContacteBundle' not
>   found in /var/www/ohupweb/app/AppKernel.php on line 20

If one works, the other doesn't works.

Of course, the two projects have an independent virtual hosts pointing to her corresponding directory.

More info: The server is a Ubuntu Server 12.04 with PHP 5.5.12 and Apache2 2.4.9. The project A is Symfony2 v2.5 and the project B is Symfony2 v2.3

What am I doing wrong? Any suggestion? Thanks.

Comment: Did you ./composer.phar install ?

Comment: What did you mean? I install them on the server using composer.

Comment: So you have a vendor folder with vendor/autoload.php in it ?

Comment: Yes, in each project. `<?php

// autoload.php @generated by Composer

require_once __DIR__ . '/composer' . '/autoload_real.php';

return ComposerAutoloaderInit2b449b980e2f41590988464a4a4ad9e6::getLoader();
`

Comment: Class not found means class not found, so it has to do with autoloading, look in this direction.

Comment: Maybe (but I would be surprised), it has to see with opcache.

Comment: The project in localhost works fine. Only fails when I execute them in server, so I think that the problem isn't the class.
The opcache configuracion in php.ini is commented, so it doesn't works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After few days looking for a solution, finally I found it!

In the configuration of php.ini I changed the commented parameter of opcache.enable to 0 and now it works... I don't know why, by the way.

Thanks anyway.