# Symfony 2.8 on Ubuntu with 2 projects only load the firth

Tags: php, apache, symfony, ubuntu

I have two project, and two virtualhost. If i load A first, B show:

ClassNotFoundException in AppKernel.php line 19:Attempted to load class "UserBundle" from namespace "B"

Did you forget a "use" statement for another namespace?

else if I reset apache and load first B all ok, but A show the same:

ClassNotFoundException in AppKernel.php line 20:Attempted to load class "UserBundle" from namespace "A"

Did you forget a "use" statement for another namespace?

and I use this apache configuration for virtualhost ( project a with a and project b with b ):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

ServerName      localhost.a

DocumentRoot    "/var/www/A/web"
DirectoryIndex  app_dev.php

<Directory "/var/www/A/web">
    AllowOverride None
    Allow from All

    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        Options -MultiViews
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app_dev.php [QSA,L]
    </IfModule>
</Directory>

CustomLog  /var/log/httpd/a-access.log combined

KeepAlive            On
MaxKeepAliveRequests 200
KeepAliveTimeout     5

<IfModule mod_filter.c>
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE "application/atom+xml" \
                                  "application/javascript" \
                                  "application/json" \
                                  "application/rss+xml" \
                                  "application/x-javascript" \
                                  "application/xhtml+xml" \
                                  "application/xml" \
                                  "image/svg+xml" \
                                  "text/css" \
                                  "text/html" \
                                  "text/javascript" \
                                  "text/plain" \
                                  "text/xml"
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header append Vary User-Agent env=!dont-vary

    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresDefault "now plus 1 week"
    ExpiresByType image/x-icon "now plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/gif    "now plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/png    "now plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg   "now plus 1 month"
</IfModule>
</VirtualHost>
```

symfony seems to work fine but i dont understand because only work first symfony

my apache:
Server version: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)
Server built:   2016-01-05T00:00:00

Comment: have you setup the bundle properly? with a UserBundle.php class that extends bundle?

Comment: yes, I can work fine, but only if are the first project open. I must restart apache for work with second project, and these work fine. The error only show if are the second project open in browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced the same problem using Symfony 2.8.x and Apache 2.4.x.

After some days of battling with my Apache configuration, I gave up and did some searches on Stack. I found this thread :
[How to configure more than one Symfony2 projects on the same server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24279568/how-to-configure-more-than-one-symfony2-projects-on-the-same-server)

As strange as it seems, the modification fixes the problem.

Basically, Angel suggested to uncomment the line : **opcache.enable = 0** in the **php.ini**.

Don't forget to restart your server.

**Update 26/10/2016 :**

In fact, the core of the issue lies in the use of xcache, maybe because I don't know to configure it properly (I tried many, many parameters and combination). I disable xcache (I remove it from the module loaded by my Apache server) and it solves the problem.

Now, I can also use opcache, for instance, I need it for Drupal 8.2.